# what is stored in the input buffer if I provide double for an int in c++?

Tags: c++

My code is :

```
int main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    cout<<"Please input first integer : ";
    x = getInt();
    cin>>z>>y;
    cout<<x <<"\n"<<z<<"\n"<<y;

    return 0;
}
```

when I provide input such as

```
Please input first integer : 34.5
34
0
-2
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.431 s
Press any key to continue.
```

What's happening over here??

Comment: where is the definition of `getInt()`?

Comment: Please remove unnecessary part of your code and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not sure if you mean what happens when you store a `double` in an `int`, an `int` in a `double`, or something completely different.

Comment: The buffer always holds the characters that haven’t been read yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to read an integer (using `>>`), the input `34.5` is no different from the strings `34abcd` or `34 42`.

The `operator>>` reads characters that could be part of an integer, `3` and `4`, and then stops (leaving the rest in the input buffer).

When continuing with `cin >> z` the buffer still contains `.5`. As the `.` cannot be part of an integer, the input fails and `z` is set to 0.

After that, the stream is in a failed state and the input to `y` isn't even attempted. The stream state has to be cleared if we want to try more input.

---

The result is complicated by the fact that `y` is still uninitialized when the values are displayed. The `-2` is one possible effect of this undefined behavior.

Comment: I'd like to add, that `z` and `y` remain uninitialized, so printing them will result in Undefined Behavior (in this case, in practice, on PC platform, printing whatever happened to be in the stack memory at those variable locations).

Comment: Oddly enough, `z` is set to 0 when the input is attempted but fails. `y` on the other hand never gets a value. :-)

Comment: I'd think `z` just happens to be 0 by chance.

Comment: @hyde: Chances are that `y`- at least for part of its lifetime -  lives in a register. You're going to get garbage, but it's unpredictable where that came from. (But this is empirical - formally you can't rely on even that)

Comment: @hyde - No, this was changed in C++11 [and now says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) *"If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set.*" (And then, with the failbit set, further extraction will not be attempted for `y`. Crazy!)

Comment: @BoPersson Ooh, TIL that. Too bad they went only half of the way, and didn't extend that to setting the value to zero-initialized or default-constructed value when called with fail bit set...

Comment: @BoPersson Is not the case in VC++ though ;) https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/285201/the-value-is-not-zeroed-after-failure-but-it-shoul.html

Answer (score 0):

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is
>   expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.

As results, subsequent calls to << are failed (failbit is set).